# Unable to detect device when inserting any USB device

Tags: usb, windows-8.1, acer-aspire

I'm running an Acer Aspire v7 with Windows 8.1 64-bit. My laptop used to work fine with USB sticks and external hard drives but then stopped one day. Device Manager shows up like this when I have a USB plugged in:

[image]

My USB devices work with other computers. I've tried uninstalling the root hubs and restarting to no avail. Plugging the flash drive and external hard drive into different ports doesn't change anything.

Comment: Possible it is missing the driver if it shows up in device manager like that. Were the ones where it worked not Windows 8.1? I assume you are using 8.1 on the one where it does not work?

Comment: None of these devices ever required downloading specific drivers. I tried looking up specific drivers too (one was a Passport hard drive) and nothing changed.
In most cases, I simply inserted these devices and they became available shortly.

Comment: And yes, it's Windows 8 on the other device. I'll have to check to see if it's 8.1.

Comment: If no USB storage devices work it sounds like you should reinstall the operating system.  Verify a keyboard won't work, if it works, then a reinstallation is unlikely to solve anything.

Comment: I currently use a Monoprice tablet via USB, repeatedly connect/disconnect this device without an issue. It only seems to be storage class devices that refuse to be identified.

Comment: It definitely is a driver issue then. For some reason your computer is not finding the right driver for it.  Wouldn't hurt to install the driver manually would it?

Comment: Since Windows is installing the device driver, how would I reinstall the driver without knowing what was originally installed? I've tried manually searching/installing a specific driver for that device, but Windows still doesn't recognize it.

Comment: Maybe try using an Ubuntu LIVE cd to verify if it is your OS or something physical?

Comment: That's a good idea, thank you. I'll try that when I get home.